# I want to convert this Cos up -1 to Tcl

Tags: tcl

can anyone tell me how can I convert this cos<sup>-1</sup> to TCL, due to in TCL 
just work with normal cos, not like this cos<sup>-1</sup>, also it calls "The inverse cosine".

Comment: Take a look at the acos function in mathfunc / expr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the reverse cosine in degree, you could use this:

```
expr {acos($x)*180/acos(-1)}
```

`acos(-1)` is pi.

Comment: Thanks,  Sir Johannes Kuhn for your answer.  it is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Tcl has always called the inverse cosine function `acos`; it's part of `expr`essions:

```
% expr { acos(0.123) }
1.4474840516030245
```

Result is in radians, of course.

Comment: Thanks Sir Donal for your answer , but I want this acosd(x)

Comment: acosd(x)=returns the inverse cosine (cosin-1) of the elements

Comment: Thanks, brother " kostix" for your answer, but "acos"  is correct that it gives the inverse. However,  it is not the same "acosd"

Comment: Just multiply it with `180/PI`

Comment: Thanks, Sir Johannes Kuhn...it works. and thanks for everyone answers on me.